# Create an extensible Ruby gem

Tags: ruby

I'm building a gem that provides a binary. This binary uses the gem's library.
I would like to make it possible to extend the features of the gem by installing other gems.

Let's say the gem is called `xyz`. I would like to be able to create the `xyz-nice_feature` that adds a nice feature.

When using a project like Rails it's ok to add dependencies in a Gemfile but in my case it's for end-users so no Gemfile.

What would be your way of doing this ?
And another question would be how to handle different versions of the extensions.

For the moment I have the following code to load the gems, but that's it:

```
Gem::Specification.find_all { |s| s.name =~ /xyz-.*/ }.map(&:name).uniq.each do |gem_name|
  gem gem_name, '>= 0'
end
```

Thank you :)

Comment: could you elaborate a little on this, i don't see where you are going...

Comment: Yup. I'm writing a file renaming tool. It provides a format string with tokens ex: '[1;5]' would return 5 characters of the original filename starting at character 1. I would like to allow other gems to add tokens. A gem xyz-id3 would provide things like [id3:author]. Is it more clear ? :)